# Pure CSS3 animation: 2 parts animation, one after the other

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to do a css3 icon animation with 2 parts: the second one has to start when the first one finishes (that part works) and on mouse out, the second part should finish before the first one does(that is the problem, it doesn't do that). Please [have a look here](http://www.elclubdelmareo.com.ar/icons/icons.html).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="iconsArea">
    <div class="icon green">
        <div class="megafono">
        <div><!-- megafono --></div>
       </div>
        <div class="wave">
        <div><!-- wave --></div>
       </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon{
    width: 126.5px;
    height: 126.5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 70px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
    border-radius: 70px;
    position: relative;
}

.green{
    background: #7ec247; 
}

 /* MEGAFONO STARTS */

 /* initial state */
div.megafono {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 22px;
    left: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    transition: all 1s ease-in; 
}

div.megafono div {
    width: 82px;
    height: 79px;
    background: url(../img/microfono.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}


 /* hover final state */
.icon:hover div.megafono {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-5px, 10px);
    -moz-transform: translate(-5px, 10px);
    -o-transform: translate(-5px, 10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(-5px, 10px);
    transform: translate(-5px, 10px);
    animation-delay: 0s, 2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s, 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 2s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s, 2s;
}
.icon:hover div.megafono div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45eg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
} 

 /* MEGAFONO ENDS */    


  /* WAVE STARTS */

 /* initial state */
div.wave {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45eg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 1s, 0s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s, 0s; /* Safari */

}

div.wave div {
    width: 24px;
    height: 43px;
    background: url(../img/wave.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}


 /* hover final state */
.icon:hover div.wave {
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}


 /* WAVE ENDS */
```

Suggestions to correct it?

Comment: I'm not sure on what you mean by _and the other way round at the end (that is the problem)_ could you elaborate?

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question itself in addition to what is happening and the expected outcome

Comment: Please have a look at the animation as it is much more clear that describing it with words, these should be the steps: 
1. On hover: The megaphone rotates.
2. The wave comes from it
3. On mouse out: The megaphone rotates back
4. The wave is out

The wave should go before the megaphone comes back to default position

Answer (score 0):

Your setup was kind of confusing so I changed up your HTML a little

```
<div class="iconsArea">
    <div class="icon green">
        <div class="megafono">
            <!-- megafono -->
        </div>
        <div class="wave">
            <!-- wave -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to get the difference in delay, you should declare the delay you want the first time in the `:hover` and the delay you want the second time in the element's properties. This may seem backwards, but you have to remember that as soon as the element is hovered the `:hover` properties affect it. As a result, the below is the outcome you're looking for I believe (prefixes removed for readability)

```
/* initial state */
 div.megafono {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 22px;
    left: 18px;
    width: 82px;
    height: 79px;
    background: url(../img/microfono.png) no-repeat;
    z-index:1;
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
/* hover final state */
.icon:hover div.megafono {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-25px);    
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
/* MEGAFONO ENDS */

/* WAVE STARTS */    
/* initial state */
 div.wave {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%; left:50px;
    width: 24px; height: 43px;
    margin-left:-12px; margin-top:-22px;
    background: url(../img/wave.png) no-repeat;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.icon:hover div.wave {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(10px) translateX(45px);
    transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLbuB/)

Comment: This is great, thank you a lot. The problem I see is that the second image is always there and appears from behind, so if the one on top has transparencies (a png or gif with transparent background) you would be able to see it waiting to get in action.
One solution is having it with opacity 0 and get 1 when it moves, but still you would be able to see a little of the one behind moving and getting the 1 opacity.

Comment: @690 I'm afraid that's what you'll have to deal with if you want elements under other elements, there's nothing I can change to accompany that besides moving closer to the top element's edge to start out with